# Is it possible to append column from file to existing table in MonetDB?

Tags: database, monetdb

Is it possible in MonetDB to append column from file to existing table or table has to be recreated? Also, is it possible to drop single column from a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could load your data into a new table with record numbers in a column then inner join.

and yes, drop column is supported